# apache beam Combine globally , has unpredictable behaviour after pipeline starts up when running on dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to get apache beam `combine globally` emits, after certain number of elements arrive.

Beam sdk version is 2.21.0 and the machine has only one cpu with 6400 MB memory.

I am consuming from multiple pubsub topics, but the pattern in which data arrives is known beforehand. Let's say continuously every 15 seconds, maximum 4 elements arrive. 3 of them from one topic and 1 from the other one. Let's call these 4 elements a batch. So I wanna put all elements of each batch, into the same window (pane) so I can process them together later on.

so I came up with this solution for putting all elements of a batch into the same pane:

```
input.apply("Windowin", Window.<PubSubMessage>into(new GlobalWindows()).withTimestampCombiner(TimestampCombiner.EARLIEST)                            
    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterFirst.of(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(4), AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(3)))))
                                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO, Window.ClosingBehavior.FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY)
                                    .discardingFiredPanes())
                    .apply("combine globally", Combine.globally(toList()))
```

I am using `elementCountAtLeast` as I know size of the batch which is maximum 4. Therefore, I expect to emit as soon as 4th element of any batch arrives and in case one element is missing, I want to emit whatever I have in current pane, 3 seconds after arrival of first element of the pane using `pastFirstElementInPane` triggerr.

The Solution seems to be correct and it works most of the time. But here are the problems:

First of all it takes so much time for pipeline to start actually processing although it says it is running. Around 3-5 minutes which is a lot.

The second problem happens when it starts to processing batches for the first time after initial 3-5 minutes boot up time. If incoming batch actually contains 4 elements, everything works, however if the batch has for example 3 elements instead of 4, then windowing should wait for 3 seconds after arrival of first element and then `combine globally` should combine whatever is in pane. Sometimes it does, but sometimes it keeps buffering all coming batches for almost 2 minutes and then `combine globally` combines all of them together.
This only happens for first emission of `combine globally` and subsequent emissions always behave correctly.

Any idea why dataflow behaves randomly after booting up?

**UPDATE 1:**

Looking at `combine globally` worker logs, it writes this:

```
2020-06-15 15:17:42.071 CEST Closing idle reader for S22-0000000000000001
2020-06-15 15:17:42.072 CEST Closing idle reader for S0-0000000000000001
2020-06-15 15:17:42.072 CEST Closing idle reader for S11-0000000000000001
```

The time `15:17:42.072`, is couple of seconds later after `combine globally` emits for the first time , which is more than 2 minutes delay.

Comment: Did you check the logs from Dataflow worker, seeking for any suspicious events during pipeline execution?

Comment: @mk_sta I checked and updated the question. Do you have any idea what do those logs mean?

Comment: What does the `input` PCollection look like? Since you have multiple `ReadFromPubSub`, how do you combine the multiple reads in the first place?

Comment: @大ドア東 i do not think `input` is the problem. But to answer your question, I read from multiple topics using java stream and collect the result as a list. So it gives me `List<PCollection< PubSubMessage >>` and then I flatten it to end up with `PCollection<PubSubMessage>` as the `input`

Comment: Do you have autoscalling enabled when you run this pipeline? Have you tried to tune up/down number of workers and check the behavior?

Comment: @mk_sta I do not have autoscaling , but honestly processing processing 4 elements every 15 secs is like nothing. It must be able to do it with 1 worker. But also as deploy dataflow per every dev branch, I wanna keep it to 1 worker

Answer (score 0):

Regarding dealing with batches, it sounds like you may be able to take things into your own hands, and try to code a solution with state and timers (see useful reading material on [state](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/) and [timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/)).

You can write a DoFn that performs the logic you want, and it will make it easier to debug as well. Now, before jumping to the code, let me mention a few things to note about the code:

- This code requires adding a constant key to all your messages, which reduces parallelism to 1. If you want to have higher parallelism again, we can iterate on the solution.
- This code will allow you to log what's happening in your pipeline. It will be useful for you as you debug it.
- You do not need to add a global combiner, because we are combining messages in the DoFn.

You can do something like this:

```java
class MyBundlingDoFn extends DoFn<KV<Integer, PubsubMessage>, List<PubsubMessage>> {
  
  @TimerId("fire")
  private final TimerSpec fireSpec = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME);

  @StateId("buffer")
  private final StateSpec<BagState<Event>> bufferedEvents = StateSpecs.bag();

  @ProcessElement
  public void process(
      ProcessContext context,
      @StateId("buffer") BagState<Event> bufferState,
      @TimerId("fire") Timer fireTimer) {

    bufferState.add(context.element());
    List<PubsubMessage> messages = Lists.newArrayList(bufferState.read());

    if (messages.size() == 1) { // Set the timer for the first message
      fireTimer.offset(Duration.standardSeconds(3)).setRelative();
    } else if (messages.size() == 4) {  // Output the 4 messages
      context.output(messages);
      bufferState.clear();
    }
  }

  @OnTimer("fire")
  public void onFire(
      OnTimerContext context,
      @StateId("buffer") BagState<Event> bufferState) {
    List<PubsubMessage> messages = Lists.newArrayList(bufferState.read());
    if (messages.size() > 0) {
      LOG.info("Outputting a total of {} messages.", messages.size());
      context.output(messages);
    }
    bufferState.clear();
  }
}
```

And for your pipeline you'd do something like this:

```java
// Your input PCollections are here:
PCollectionTuple inputCollections = PCollectionTuple.of(pubsubPColl1).and(pubsubPColl2();

PCollection<List<PubsubMessages>> batcedhMessages = inputCollectionsTuple
    // Stateful operations require a key, so we assign a constant key of 1.
    // Note that this will reduce your parallelism to 1.
    // This should be fine because you're performing global combines, 
    // but you may need to change it later to increase throughput.
    .apply(WithKeys.of(1))
    // We then apply our dofn
    .apply(ParDo.of(new MyBundlingDoFn());
```

---

Finally, about your question regarding the 5 minute start-up time:

> First of all it takes so much time for pipeline to start actually processing although it says it is running. Around 3-5 minutes which is a lot.

Unfortunately, for Dataflow this is 'normal'. Jobs take a few minutes to start because VMs are provisioned and set up.

Comment: Thanks pablo for writing this stateful sample for me. But it does not answer my question about unexpected combineGlobally behaviour at star up. Also it does not work for me as a workaround. As I put in my sample code I need to put all elements of an incoming batch, into same pane. Because later on I have a GroupByKey in my pipelines which needs elements to be bounded. In your workaround, Is it possible to manually output elements within unique panes?